# Android: local tests with code coverage?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-testing, jacoco

I want to define unit tests for my classes and am running into the following issue. If I define the unit test inside the androidTest folder (testing with instrumentation) then the test runs normally with valid results. If, however, I define the test inside the test folder (local testing) then running the test generates a message "class not found: "[classname]" Empty test suite". This wouldn't be so bad and I would just run all tests from androidTest, except that I want to use code coverage and Android Studio doesn't allow me to run coverage tests from androidTest, but only from test.

Why isn't Android Studio able to find the unit tests when they are defined in the test folder, but is able to when they are defined in the androidTest folder?

Code:

```
public class SomeTest{

    private Context mInstrumentationCtx;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mInstrumentationCtx = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
        // do some setup actions
    }

    @Test
    public void testFirst() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertEquals(true, true);
    }

}
```

Gradle config:

```
android {

testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }
}

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile ('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
```

Comment: how do you run the tests (that fail) ? Have you tried to run on one class/dir level?

Comment: Right click on test class - "run [testname] with coverage"

Comment: works as expected in freshly created project in latest AS, we can try finding the diff

Comment: whats your gradle version?

Comment: version is: 2.3.0-beta1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be not an answer per se

You could try changing

```
 testCompile ('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
```

to

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

which seems to be default runner in recent gradle versions.

It works for me with the latter but fails with the former

---

Edit:

After some struggle it looks like downgrade to version 2.2.3 is *a* solution for now, smth must have changed in 2.3 beta that author has used

Comment: I've tried replacing it but I still get the failure "Process finished with exit code 1 .. Empty test suite"

Comment: what's InstrumentationRegistry in your case? is it supposed to run in deviceless setup?

Comment: I want to run tests for an Sqlite wrapper and it needs a context,  hence the instrumentationRegistry. I've tried commenting out that line but the test fails the same way

Comment: sorry im clueless, whats your build tool version? would you mind trying gradle:2.2.3 ?

Comment: buildToolsVersion "25.0.2" - sure, I'll try. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: it still insists that there's an empty test suite and won't run the test

Comment: oh, would you mind sharing more of your gradle file, the part you pasted is sure incomplete

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132593/discussion-between-jon-and-oleg-bogdanov).